# How do I fetch in Remix JS from a specific (back-end) API link / Database URL?

Tags: remix, remix.run

I am trying to follow the Jokes tutorial @https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/jokes
and I was wondering how do I fetch from a specific (back-end) API link / Database URL?

Can you provide an example (where you use Prisma)?

On the webpage it says "You can use any persistence solution you like with Remix; Firebase, Supabase, Airtable, Hasura, Google Spreadsheets, Cloudflare Workers KV, Fauna, a custom PostgreSQL, or even your backend team's REST/GraphQL APIs"

I have set the DATABASE_URL in the .env file to the API link, however I don't know how to continue from here

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some code, so we can help you based on a specific question.

In general, you would fetch data inside your `loader` function in Remix. That function runs on your server and can be used to fetch from a database or API.

If you have trouble with Prisma, I would suggest you have a look at the tutorial you are following or look at the Prisma documentation.

You can find more information about data loading in Remix in the Remix documentation: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/data-loading